# Loop over dataframes to create new variable

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, lapply

I have 30 dataframes and I need to create a new variable in each of them based on a number of conditions.
I am trying to do a for loop, but I am not getting it. I searched for some examples on here, but I dint get too far. Any help please?

What I have done is:

```
dflist <- c("chr1", "chr2","chr3","chr4","chr5","chr6","chr7","chr8","chr9","chr10",
            "chr11","chr12","chr13","chr14","chr15","chr16","chr17","chr18",
            "chr19","chr20","chr21","chr22","chr23","chr24","chr25","chr26","chr27",
            "chr28","chr29","chr30")


for (df in dflist){
for (i in 1:length(df)){
df[i,]$Dist2 =   ifelse(df[i,]$Dist <= 10000,1, 
            ifelse(df[i,]$Dist > 10000 & df[i,]$Dist <= 20000 ,2,
            ifelse(df[i,]$Dist > 20000 & df[i,]$Dist <= 30000 ,3,
        ifelse(df[i,]$Dist > 30000 & df[i,]$Dist <= 40000 ,4,
        ifelse(df[i,]$Dist > 40000 & df[i,]$Dist <= 50000 ,5,
        ifelse(df[i,]$Dist > 50000 & df[i,]$Dist <= 60000 ,6,
        ifelse(df[i,]$Dist > 60000 & df[i,]$Dist <= 70000 ,7,
        ifelse(df[i,]$Dist > 70000 & df[i,]$Dist <= 80000 ,8,
        ifelse(df[i,]$Dist > 80000 & df[i,]$Dist <= 90000 ,9,
        ifelse(df[i,]$Dist > 90000 & df[i,]$Dist <= 100000 ,10,NA))))))))))}}
```

Each file looks like this:

```
     Chr   SNP1   SNP2  Dist  Sign   r2
1     26 507478 507479  9727    + 0.789
2     26 507478 507480 13907    - 0.093
3     26 507478 507481 23618    - 0.002
4     26 507478 507482 59349    - 0.245
5     26 507478 507483 62804    + 0.266
6     26 507478 507484 65323    + 0.029
```

Thanks a lot.
Cheers.
Paula

Comment: I guess you can use `cut` instead of the `ifelse` i.e. `cut(df$Dist, breaks=c(-Inf, seq(10000, 100000, by =10000), Inf))` and specify the `labels`

Comment: If you have a `list`, `lapply(lst, function(x) cut(x$Dist, breaks=c(-Inf, seq(10000, 100000, by =10000), Inf), labels=c(1:10, NA)))`

Comment: @akrun Thank you. But it does not work. I get the message: "Error in x$Dist : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors".

Comment: Please check the `str(lst)`.  Is it a matrix?

Comment: @akrun I made it a matrix, but I still get the same error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it is a matrix, it won't work.  I thought you have data.frames.  I did try it on the example data you provided.  It seems to work for me.

Comment: @akrun I am sorry. Each "file" is a dataframe. str(df1): 'data.frame':   44005875 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ X..Chr: int  26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 ...
 $ SNP1  : int  507478 507478 507478 507478 507478 507478 507478 507478 507478 507478 ...
 $ SNP2  : int  507479 507480 507481 507482 507483 507484 507485 507486 507487 507488 ...
 $ Dist  : int  9727 13907 23618 59349 62804 65323 66781 73715 83693 88691 ...
 $ Sign  : chr  "+" "-" "-" "-" ...
 $ r2    : num  0.789 0.093 0.002 0.245 0.266 0.029 0.002 0.006 0.106 0.006 ...

Comment: In that case, it worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `lst` data from akrun's answer, here's another possible approach using `ceiling()`

```
lapply(lst, function(x) {
    ## divide 'Dist' by 10,000 and push to the next integer
    y <- ceiling(x$Dist / 1e4)
    ## replace the values over 10 with NA
    is.na(y) <- y > 10
    ## bind the data to the new vector
    cbind(x, Dist2 = y)
})
# [[1]]
#   Chr   SNP1   SNP2   Dist Sign    r2 Dist2
# 1  26 507478 507479 123300    + 0.789    NA
# 2  26 507478 507480  13907    - 0.093     2
# 3  26 507478 507481  23618    - 0.002     3
# 4  26 507478 507482  59349    - 0.245     6
# 5  26 507478 507483  62804    + 0.266     7
# 6  26 507478 507484  65323    + 0.029     7
#
# [[2]]
#   Chr   SNP1   SNP2  Dist Sign    r2 Dist2
# 1  26 507478 507479  9727    + 0.789     1
# 2  26 507478 507480 13907    - 0.093     2
# 3  26 507478 507481 23618    - 0.002     3
# 4  26 507478 507482 59349    - 0.245     6
# 5  26 507478 507483 62804    + 0.266     7
# 6  26 507478 507484 65323    + 0.029     7
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `cut`.  We keep the data.frames in a `list` ('lst'), loop through the `list` with `lapply` and `transform` the data.frame by creating another column 'Dist2' using `cut`.

```
lapply(lst, transform, Dist2= cut(Dist, 
      breaks=c(-Inf,seq(1e4, 1e5, by=1e4), Inf), labels=c(1:10, NA)))
#[[1]]
#  Chr   SNP1   SNP2   Dist Sign    r2 Dist2
#1  26 507478 507479 123300    + 0.789  <NA>
#2  26 507478 507480  13907    - 0.093     2
#3  26 507478 507481  23618    - 0.002     3
#4  26 507478 507482  59349    - 0.245     6
#5  26 507478 507483  62804    + 0.266     7
#6  26 507478 507484  65323    + 0.029     7

#[[2]]
#  Chr   SNP1   SNP2  Dist Sign    r2 Dist2
#1  26 507478 507479  9727    + 0.789     1
#2  26 507478 507480 13907    - 0.093     2
#3  26 507478 507481 23618    - 0.002     3
#4  26 507478 507482 59349    - 0.245     6
#5  26 507478 507483 62804    + 0.266     7
#6  26 507478 507484 65323    + 0.029     7
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(structure(list(Chr = c(26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L),
SNP1 = c(507478L, 
507478L, 507478L, 507478L, 507478L, 507478L), SNP2 = 507479:507484, 
    Dist = c(123300, 13907, 23618, 59349, 62804, 65323), Sign = c("+", 
    "-", "-", "-", "+", "+"), r2 = c(0.789, 0.093, 0.002, 0.245, 
    0.266, 0.029)), .Names = c("Chr", "SNP1", "SNP2", "Dist", 
"Sign", "r2"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
 class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(Chr = c(26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L), SNP1 = c(507478L, 
    507478L, 507478L, 507478L, 507478L, 507478L), SNP2 = 507479:507484, 
        Dist = c(9727L, 13907L, 23618L, 59349L, 62804L, 65323L
        ), Sign = c("+", "-", "-", "-", "+", "+"), r2 = c(0.789, 
        0.093, 0.002, 0.245, 0.266, 0.029)), .Names = c("Chr", 
    "SNP1", "SNP2", "Dist", "Sign", "r2"), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")))
```